# Registering Generics in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have some Unity DI in a project that is causing dependency registration unit tests to fail.  I think it's because I have the syntax wrong on registering the generics.  I suppose it could be something else I'm not seeing.  In any case, I tried to follow [this article][1] to register the generics, but I found it lacking and confusing, so I still haven't gotten there.  It mentions Unity classes like `InjectionConstructor` and `GenericaParameter` but in trying to use these, I'm getting various compile time errors.  I'm also not finding anything here on SO to clear things up.  I am hoping someone here might have a more clear explanation for how to register these things (or some other answer, if that's not the issue).

Here is some relevant code:

First is my top level interface which will be injected in and used by client code, specifying a type for T.

```
namespace Elided.Extraction.Interfaces
{
    public interface IDataExtractionService<out T>
    {
        T GetData(Stream stream);
    }
}
```

This next class is the implementation which has an injectable IDataExtractor:

```
namespace Elided.Extraction
{
    public class DataExtractionService<T> : IDataExtractionService<T>
    {
        private readonly IDataExtractor<T> extractor;

        internal DataExtractionService(IDataExtractor<T> extractor)
        {
            this.extractor = extractor;
        }

        public T GetData(Stream workbookStream)
        {
            // elided
            return this.extractor.GetData(elidedArgument)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the interface for the IDataExtractor:

```
namespace Elided.Extraction.Behaviors.Interfaces
{
    internal interface IDataExtractor<out T>
    {
        T GetData(object elidedArgument);
    }
}
```

Here's an implementation of IDataExtractor.  It's an implementation of type DataSet, but the idea is that numerous implementations could exist, allowing the client code to have an injectable IDataExtractionService or any other type for which an extractor implementation is written.

```
namespace Elided.Extraction.Behaviors
{
    internal class DataSetExtractor : IDataExtractor<DataSet>
    {
        public DataSet GetData(object elidedArgument)
        {
            // implementation elided
            // returns a DataSet
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my registration code (in the same assembly as the above stuff) which I don't believe is working:

```
public void RegisterDependencies(IDependencyContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataExtractionService<>), typeof(DataExtractionService<>));
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataExtractor<DataSet>), typeof(DataSetExtractor));
}
```

Update: The specific error message comes from an Exception throw by a unit test:

> Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type DataExtractionService`1
>   cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this
>   value.   [1]:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660936(v=pandp.20).aspx

Comment: What is the problem? Are you having a compilation error? At which line? Or are you having a runtime exception? What is it if so?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - My unit test fails and shows the following message from an exception:

Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type ExcelDataExtractionService`1 cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

Comment: You have `IDataExtractionService<>` configured for any generic type. But the only registration for `IDataExtractor<T>` is for `IDataExtractor<DataSet>`. So you can't resolve `IDataExtractionService<>` for anything *except* `IDataExtractionService<DataSet>`. Otherwise, whatever generic type you use for `IDataExtractionService<>` it's going to need a corresponding `IDataExtractor<>`,  but the only one is for `DataSet`.

Comment: @ScottHannen - So, should I supply a default implementation like... IDataExtractor<> --> DataExtractor >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pasted your code and created a unit test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUnityConfiguration()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        //This part is copied from your Unity configuration.
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataExtractionService<>), typeof(DataExtractionService<>));
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IDataExtractor<DataSet>), typeof(DataSetExtractor));
        var x = container.Resolve<IDataExtractionService<DataSet>>();
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(x, typeof(DataExtractionService<DataSet>));
        var y = container.Resolve<IDataExtractor<DataSet>>();
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(y, typeof(DataSetExtractor));
    }
```

The first one failed because `DataExtractionService` doesn't have a public constructor, so Unity can't create it.

I tried entries in AssemblyInfo.cs to make internals visible to Unity, but that didn't work.

I read some more - there isn't a workaround for hidden constructors. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942211/how-can-i-use-unity-with-internal-classes).

You can make the constructor public, but then you'll also need to make `IDataExtractor<T>` public. With that change I was able to resolve instances of both registrations.

Comment: I was able to get this working by making those underlying pieces public, which I'm not thrilled about.  I'll have to decide if I'd rather keep the DI and have these pieces be public, or, at a certain depth in the chain, go concrete and keep things internal.

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood.  I was able to leave the classes internal and just set the constructor to public.  That took care of it and kept my lower level assembly details hidden!