# Does dependency injection enlarge the scope of a class which could be "internal"?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, dependency-injection, orchardcms

If I am going to use DTOs to pass data cross layers/assemblies instead of persistent classes, I could limit the access to the classes in persistent model to objects within the same assembly.

But in system like Orchard CMS (which is using NHibernate for ORM, AutoFac for Dependency Injection), persistence is via another assembly in which provides `IRepository<T>` for persistence, the system will inject `IRepository<T>` to my assembly at one of class constructor, thus it requires persistent class T to be public. Without dependency injection, I could define T as internal and utilize `IRepository<T>` within my assembly code, does dependency injection requires the class to be public all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in order for the container to be able to instantiate and supply dependencies, [it generally requires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947525/314291)<sup>1</sup> that scope of injectable dependencies be expanded to `public`.

In fact, another common (and misguided) "gripe" of the dependency inversion principal was that all of the class's internal dependencies, which are now injected, are typically exposed on a public constructor - seemingly in violation of the original "3 Amigos" principals of OO, which had the internal dependencies of a class firmly hidden away from public view.

The trade-off was of course that this coupled a class to its dependencies directly via `new` instantiation, which prevents decoupling and worse, hampers testing, which in post-SOLID era code, is recognized as a first class design concern.

One thing to remember is that by convention, coupling between classes should invariably be through interfaces - this way, the only actors actually "using" these public classes and constructors will be the container itself, as well as your unit tests.

By example:

**Repository Assembly**

```
public interface IFooRepo
{
     Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> FindFoos(Predicate predicate);
     // ...
}

// For IoC and testing purposes, MyFooRepo must be public
public class MyFooRepo : IFooRepo
{
    // .. Implement
}
```

**Service Assembly**

```
// Note : No indication of the IFooRepository dependency here
public interface IMyService
{
    Task DoAmazingThingsWithFoo();
}

// MyService class must also be public for IoC and tests
public class MyService : IMyService
{
     private readonly IMyRepo _repo;
     // Dependencies are publically visible on the constructor
     public MyService(IMyRepo repo)
     {
        _repo = repo;
     }
   // ... Implement
 }
```

**IoC BootStrapping**

```
Bind<IFooRepo>().To<MyFooRepo>(); // Can also specify lifetimes etc
Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>();
```

Further reading - Mark Seemann defends [public scope](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/21/public-types-hidden-in-plain-sight/) in depth.

---

<sub>[1] Steven is the primary author of SimpleInject</sub>

Comment: You pointed out that "the coupling should typically be against interfaces" and although my example also against an interface, but the interface itself bind to a public class (IRepository<T>), thus the coupling is still against class instead of interface, is there a better way so that I can still  couple to interface only?

Comment: I meant classes dependent on other classes should only be coupled via interfaces (the D of SOLID). IoC bootstrapping itself is never an elegant affair - it will generally define the concrete classes to be used when an interface dependency is required (some IoC's will even auto-bind based on naming convention). I've updated with an example - hopefully this clarifies.